# CS0103: The name 'rand' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

I know this error has been the center of about a dozen questions, but I'm not seeing my situation in any of those other questions.

I have the following at the top of an aspx page:

```
<% String rand = new Random().Next().ToString(); %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js?v=<%=rand%>"></script>
```

It builds just fine, but when the page is accessed, I get the error complaining about the `<%=rand%>` part of the line saying it doesn't know what `rand` is. As a large web application, we're not wanting to cache code that changes frequently and this is the approach we're taking. In fact, this exact approach works on another page of ours but is not working on this page for some reason. We want to only generate one random number because it's used across multiple js files that we don't want cached.

I've looked through many of the other CS0103 questions but none of them I read talk about variables created in the markup of the aspx page.

Comment: are you maybe missing the runat="server" attribute on the head element in your production code?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/script.js?v=<asp:Literal id="randNum" runat="server" />"></script>
```

And then in your code behind.

```
randNum.Text = new Random().Next().ToString();
```

As a side note though, using this method to prevent caching is a bit of a hack. If you are using .NET 4.5, I would suggest looking into the scriptBundle and styleBundle classes, which essentially implement this methodology as well as minify your scripts/css.